# MonoTouch.Dialog - Responding to DetailDisclosureButton Taps

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

The `Element` class has a `Tapped` event which can be used to respond to taps of the element.

However, when a element has its accessory set to `DetailDisclosureButton`, there is no way it seems to respond to the tap of the `DetailDisclosureButton`.

Using MonoTouch.Dialog, how do we respond to the `DetailDisclosureButton` tap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it does not look possible without editing or *better* inheriting from `DialogViewController` since the `UITableViewSource` (or `UITableViewDelegate`) method `AccessoryButtonTapped` is not overridden by MonoTouch.Dialog itself.

To fix this you can **override** `DialogViewController.CreateSizingSource` to return your own `Source` which **overrides** `AccessoryButtonTapped`.

IMO that's something that should be part of MonoTouch.Dialog so you're welcome to send a *pull* request to Miguel (or I'll do it myself later).

**UPDATE** [patch](https://gist.github.com/1379500) for immediate enjoyment

Comment: Excellent. MonoTouch without MonoTouch.Dialog would make MonoTouch useless for us Enterprise developers making line of business apps. I'd vote to have MTD included into MonoTouch :)

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com look at first item on the (yet to be released) MonoTouch 5.1 (beta) http://ios.xamarin.com/Releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.1

Comment: That is outstanding! Will it get updated as often as the GIT version does? Having all those people contribute to it has made MT.dialog library an outstanding resource. We're probably going to buy MonoDroid, but really need MonoDriod.Dialog to sell it to the enterprise.

Comment: Too soon to say for sure - but I suspect every new version of MT will get an updated MT.D from GIT. There's a MonoDroid.Dialog available on GIT (I use it for Andr.Unit) but it's not from Xamarin and it's not (yet) as easy/powerful as the MonoTouch version.